# How is Young's inequality applied in this equation?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the book Superlinear Parabolic Problems Blow-up, Global Existence and Steady States, page 493 this equation appears in which the book says it uses Young's inequality

$$ |\Omega| u^p \leq ku^q +\epsilon(k)u $$

where $\epsilon(k) = C(|\Omega|,p,q) k^{{-(p-1)}/{(q-p)}}$.
The only things that are given are that $p<q$ ($p$ and $q$ are not conjugate exponents) and $k>0$ ($k$ can be taken large enough). I am failing to see how this is an application of classical [Young inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products).
Is this really an application of the classic young inequality or is it an application of some modification of it?

**attempt:** The best I've achieved so far using Young's inequality was

$$ u^p = [\left( k \frac{(p-1)}{q} \right)^{-(p-1)/q}u][(\left( k \frac{(p-1)}{q} \right)^{(p-1)/q}u^{p-1}] \leq \dfrac{q}{(p-1)}[\left( k \frac{(p-1)}{q} \right)^{(p-1)/q}u^{p-1}]^{q/(p-1)} +   \dfrac{q}{(q-p+1)}[\left( k \frac{(p-1)}{q} \right)^{-(p-1)/q}u]^{q/(q-p+1)}  \leq ku^q+Ck^{-(p-1)/(q-p+1)}u^{q/(q-p+1)}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $1 \le p$ in the problem, as I believe the inequality is false without this assumption.  Let's assume this.

The estimate is trivial if $p=1$ since you're free to make the constant on the second term larger than $|\Omega|$.

Assume then that $1 < p < q$.  Then write
$$
u^{p} = u^{p-1/r} u^{1/r}
$$
for $1 < r < \infty$ and apply the standard Young inequality to bound
$$
u^{p-1/r} u^{1/r} \le \frac{1}{r'} u^{r'(p-1/r)} + \frac{1}{r} u.
$$
Now, $r' = r/(r-1)$, so
$$
r'(p-1/r) = \frac{rp-1}{r-1}.
$$
We now want to choose $1 < r < \infty$ such that $(rp-1)/(r-1) =q$.  Simple algebra shows this is equivalent to
$$
r = \frac{q-1}{q-p}
$$
and this satisfies $r>1$ precisely due to the assumptions that $1 < p < q$.  We have thus proved that
$$
u^p \le \frac{p-1}{q-1} u^q + \frac{q-p}{q-1} u.
$$
We're now most of the way there as we have our "basic" Young inequality.  We now apply this to $\varepsilon u$, and divide through by $\varepsilon^p$ to see that
$$
u^p \le \frac{p-1}{q-1} \varepsilon^{q-p} u^q + \frac{q-p}{q-1} \varepsilon^{1-p} u.
$$
We can now get your desired bound by choosing $\varepsilon$ appropriately.

Comment: got it, i'm not good at using tricks to get inequalities, thanks for the great answer.

Comment: You're welcome, @Ilovemath.  The more "tricks" you learn, the more they turn into "techniques."  :)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use the splitting
$$
u^p = u^ru^{p-r}
$$
with
$$
r = \frac{p-1}{q-1}q,
$$
and apply the Young inequality with the exponents
$$
\frac{q-1}{p-1} \qquad\textrm{and}\qquad \frac{q-1}{q-p}.
$$